# python module import issues in command prompt

Tags: python, import, module

I have installed some python packages which I am able to access using IDLE and not through command shell window.

Here is the output from IDLE:

```
Python 2.7.2+ (default, Oct  4 2011, 20:03:08) 
[GCC 4.6.1] on linux2
Type "copyright", "credits" or "license()" for more information.
==== No Subprocess ====
>>> import whoosh
```

Here is the output from my terminal:

```
pradeep@ubuntu:~$ python
Python 2.7.2 (default, Nov 28 2011, 23:56:33) 
[GCC 4.6.1] on linux3
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import whoosh
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named whoosh
```

How can I point the terminal python to IDLE python packages? Why is terminal showing 'linux3' where as IDLE showing 'linux2'? Please help me with this path issue. thanks.

**Update1:**

Thanks all. Like most of you guessed, I have two different versions installed.

My Idle Path shows

```
['/home/pradeep', '/usr/bin', '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/Whoosh-2.3.0-py2.7.egg', '/usr/lib/python2.7', '/usr/lib/python2.7/plat-linux2', '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-tk', '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-old', '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload', '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages', '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages', '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/PIL', '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gst-0.10', '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gtk-2.0', '/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7', '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ubuntu-sso-client', '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ubuntuone-client', '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ubuntuone-control-panel', '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ubuntuone-couch', '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ubuntuone-installer', '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ubuntuone-storage-protocol']
```

My terminal path shows:

```
['', '/usr/local/lib/python27.zip', '/usr/local/lib/python2.7', '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/plat-linux3', '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/lib-tk', '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/lib-old', '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload', '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages']
```

How do I remove the terminal version and install IDLE version in terminal? Thanks.

Comment: You can try to export PYTHONPATH to point to where whoosh is installed also check your LD_LIBRARY_PATH

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're running two different Python installs, one dated 10/4/2011 and the other dated 11/28/2011.  The second one doesn't have *whoosh* installed.

Your options are:

1. Look for the version that IDLE uses and run it from the command-line.  To find it, turn on IDLE and run `import sys; print sys.executable`.  That will show you the location of the version with the packages installed.
2. Or you can beef-up your command-line version by installing those same packages at the command-line (i.e. run `python setup.py install` for the various packages you want to load.

Answer (score 3):

Packages are searched in all the directories defined in the python path.

So, if the `IDLE` and `terminal` are working differently - means they have difference in their python paths.

So,

Try this : (On both IDLE and terminal)

```
import sys
print sys.path  # this prints the list of directories in the python path.
```

Compare the list that you get from both and the extra directory in IDLE will be having `whoosh`

You can add directories to `sys.path` like this :

```
import sys
sys.path.append('/home/user/packages')
```

Now, all packages in `/home/user/packages` will be available for import.

Comment: This generally happens when you have different python installations, so different `sys.path` and when you install a new package that gets installed to one of your python installations.

Comment: This works, but only temporarily (in my experience). setting PYTHONPATH will make terminal always have the modules available.

Comment: I know that would be better - but by this I want him to see what's causing the problem.

Comment: @YugalJindle, you are right.  How do I remove terminal version and make it point to IDLE version. If I use apt-get remove python, I am not sure which version will get deleted?

Comment: I would have removed both.. and then reinstalled the one that I wanted to have. That is the best thing when you want to save time from troubleshooting - When there is nothing to loose.

Comment: @YugalJindle, I tried moving the terminal python by using "sudo apt-get remove python" and my desktop crashed. the kernel still runs though. I dont think I did anything wrong but now my faith in ubuntu has dimisined. sigh

Comment: I prefer Mint, its ubuntu minus problems.

Answer (score 1):

You need to make sure `PYTHONPATH` is set correctly in your `~/.profile` or `/usr/<user-name>/.profile`.

For example (this is for OS X, but just find where Python is installed on your machine):

```
export PYTHONPATH="/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-package/:$PYTHONPATH"
```

Only OS X requires the export prefix, and you can check your current path using `echo $PYTHONPATH` in terminal.

Once you've changed `PYTHONPATH` to point to your version of python's package folder, you need to force terminal to update the path using this:

```
source ~/.profile
```

Then try `echo $PYTHONPATH` again and make sure it changed. Then you should be set as long as you pointed to the correct directory.

Answer (score 0):

This is due to path issues. I would recommend using virtual envs and pip as standard when working with packages you've imported or obatined externally.

Some great notes here: https://python-guide.readthedocs.org/en/latest/

Hope this helps.